# Is "aways" a misprint by EVE Online Customer Support?

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

> We noticed that you have not yet logged in to EVE Online. You're just a few steps **aways** to get started in the world of wealth, power, adventure and opportunity that is New Eden!

EVE Online Customer Support sent me an email that has this text and I've never seen "**just a few steps aways**". Is it a misprint? Shouldn't it be "**a few steps away**"?

Comment: Even if you change "aways" to "away" it still sounds strange.  I would have written "You're just a few steps *away from getting* started..."

Comment: Eve Online's developers, CCP Games, are based out of Iceland, so they may not be native English speakers.

Comment: I believe **aways** is a vestigial adverbial genitive (in the native wild, that is) -- the particular quote does not seem idiomatic to me for other reasons; it should be **a step aways from getting**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make no mistake, it's a typo. **you're just a few steps away from something** is a very popular expression in English. This expression, however, is not listed in any known to me dictionary for some inexplicable to me reason, but I personally hear it a lot. And it fits the context perfectly too because that's the kind of phraseology they often use in marketing and advertising. The sentence otherwise just doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Example:

> **You're just a few steps aways** from finally making your dream come true. All you have to do is pick up your phone and dial the following number.

And as Readin pointed out in his comment, it actually would be better to say **away from getting started**.

Comment: Not sure why the phrase would need to be in a dictionary: the meaning of "just a few steps away" is immediate from the definitions of the individual words, with "steps" meaning either the things you take when walking (e.g., "You're just a few steps away from Starbucks") or "actions/stages" (as in the question) as appropriate.

Comment: Whether it's a typo, colloquialism, or mistaken belief that "away" has to be pluralized to match "steps" isn't quite clear.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the quotation is from someone who has heard native speakers use **aways**, but they haven't got it quite right.  This would be idiomatic:

> You're just a step aways from getting...

**aways** is a (vestigial) adverbial genitive.

> Did you see a roan mare come a-gallopin by?
>   --I reckon I did. She went off that-aways.

Or

> People came from as far aways as Chicago.

Comment: That's interesting. If I came up to you and told you that there was something wrong with that quote and asked you to modify it, how would you change it?

Comment: I don't quite get your hypothetical, @Cookie Monster.

Comment: Would you say that the way it's written is wrong?

Comment: I have said so. Twice.

Comment: How would you modify it to make it a correct sentence?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: I don't think your first quote is very idiomatic, I don't think I've ever seen "aways" there, just "away". As for your second, that does remain as an idiom.

Comment: Agree with @jaxad0127, I've never heard "aways" used like that (native speaker).  The closest I've seen is "you're a ways away from getting..." or "there's a ways to go", which implies you are a *long* way away

Comment: Well, @jaxad0127, it may be because you have not lived in or traveled to places where people speak like this.

Comment: Haven't you ever been told *You're an inch aways from getting smacked in the kisser!* ?

Comment: Just saying as a native speaker I can't recall ever seeing that in modern speech. Dialect differences should probably be called out on a site like this.

Comment: You will hear it more often than you see it.